# Resolving complex named type in Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, dependency-resolver

//I am trying to resolve a complex named type in Autofac which is getting resolved properly and //easily in Unitycontainer. But facing issues

//I tried the following
//I have a mail MailTopic class which looks like

```
class MailTopic
{
    public virtual bool IsEnabled { get; set; } = true;
    public virtual string TopicName { get; set; }
    public virtual string From { get; set; }
    public virtual string FromDisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual string To { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CC { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MailTopicTemplate> Templates { get; set; }
}
```

// MailTopicTemplate class

```
class MailTopicTemplate
{
    public virtual string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual string TemplateFile { get; set; }
    public virtual string Template { get; set; }
}
```

// Structure of mailtopic in appsettings file

```
"mailtopics": {
    "mailtopic": [
        {
            "topicName": "complianceCheckNotification",
            "from": "blabla",
            "fromDisplayName": "blablalbla",
            "to": "myself",
            "templates": [
                {
                    "templatename": "generic",
                    "subject": "important",
                    "templatefile": "Templates\\Compliance.html"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "topicName": "techReportnotification",
            "from": "blabla",
            "fromDisplayName": "blablalbla",
            "to": "myself",
            "templates": [
                {
                    "templatename": "technical",
                    "subject": "important",
                    "templatefile": "Templates\\Technical.html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

//in unitycontainer
`container.Resolve<MailTopic>("complianceCheckNotification")`
//is resolving the mailtopic properly

// Autofac registration and resolution

```
builder.RegisterType<MailTopic>().Named<MailTopic>("complianceCheckNotification");
    MailTopic topic = builder.ResolveNamed<MailTopic>("complianceCheckNotification");
```

I am getting null values in the topic except the IsEnabled
Could someone please let me know how to achieve this in Autofac

Comment: _"in unitycontainer...."_ - and how do you register it in the unity container?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why are you expecting Autofac to read the data from some JSON file. `RegisterType` will just register type hooking it with DI. Basically in your case you are registering `new MailTopic()` as provider factory, it knows nothing about settings, JSON files, etc.

Depending on the use case you can read the data from the config and use `RegisterInstance` to add it to the DI container. For example (assuming the JSON provided in the question):

```
var mailTopics = configuration.GetSection("mailtopics:mailtopic").Get<List<MailTopic>>();
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
foreach (var mailTopic in mailTopics)
{
    builder.RegisterInstance(mailTopic).Named<MailTopic>(mailTopic.TopicName);
}

var container = builder.Build();
MailTopic topic = container.ResolveNamed<MailTopic>("complianceCheckNotification");
```

See also:

- [Autofac: Registration Concepts](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html)

Comment: Thanks @Guru Stron. But Unitycontainer was doing it without registering the mailtopics by picking them from Appsettings file. I wonder how.

Comment: @ravikiranreddy not an expert in unity container. You need to check how exactly it was registering the topics in the container. Possibly it was using some specific registration provider. Autofac supports reading it's config from JSON/XML file but AFAIK it requires different format then you have used.